# The $NODE_CONFIG environment variable is malformed JSON

Tags: node.js, express

I am new in Node. I am trying to start a node service by using the following command --

`export NODE_CONFIG_DIR=/var/www/api/config NODE_ENV=development PORT=3018; node /var/www/api/app.js`

Inside the config directory I have the following file development.json

```
{
  "general": {
    "port": 3018
  },
  "database": {
    "connectionString":  "mongodb://***:***@url:port/api?replicaSet=set-578f3ed7000587"
  },
  "environmentName": "Development"
}
```

And I am getting the following line after starting node

`The $NODE_CONFIG environment variable is malformed JSON
API listening on port 3018!`

When I try accessing the api in browser I get 502 bad gateway. The node is running though.

Any help is highly appreciated.

Comment: Sounds like an issue with the node-config package, not node or express. How did you set the `NODE_CONFIG` env variable and what operating system are you on?

Comment: I am on Ubuntu 14 . I don't know because I didn't setup node_config.